# Perl regex expression

Tags: regex, perl, parsing, scripting

I have inherited a perl script that pulls data out of some files.  The whole script works fine but recently some engineers have been putting in more than one number for a certain spot that usually took one number, so the output is not showing all of what is expected.

Sample input:

`CRXXXX: "Then some text"`

`CRs XXXX, XXXX, XX, XXX`

`CRXXX "Some Text"`

Currently this regex statement I have pulls out the number after the CR, but if given then second line of sample input it prints `"s XXXX, XXXX, XX, XXX"` instead of the wanted `"XXXX XXXX XX XXX"`

I am very new to perl and am struggling to figure out how to alter this regex to work on all of the inputs.

```
 $temp_comment =~ s/\s[cC][rR][-\s:;]*([\d])/\n$1/mg;
```

Thanks in advance!

Brock

Comment: This is very unclear. Can't you give us some *real* data and the corresponding output that you want please? Are the `X` characters supposed to be digits?

Comment: Brock, What is the expected output of the other two lines of input? Is your regex supposed to match the CRXXX portion, or the "Some Text" that follows?

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: YEs the X's are digits sorry for forgetting to mention that.  The expected output for the other lines is simply the digits following "CR" so for instance if CR1234: "blah blah blah" it would change to 1234. or if CR999 "random text" just change to 999

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sample data like:

```
my $temp_comment =
'CR1234: "Then some text"
 CRs 2345, 3456, 45, 567
 CR678 "Some Text"';
```

try:

```
$temp_comment =~ s/(,)|[^\d\n]+/$1?' ':''/semg;
```

or, if you want to stay close to the string templates:

```
$temp_comment =~ s/ ^                 # multi-line mode, line start
                    \s*               # leading blanks?
                    CR                # CR tag
                    \D*               # non-number stuff
                     (                  # start capture group
                      (?:\d+ [,\s]*)+   # find (number, comma, space) groups
                     )                  # end capture group
                    \D*               # skip remaining non-number stuff
                    $                 # multi-line mode, line end
                  /$1/mxg;            # set multi-line mode + regex comments "x"
```

but you'd have to remove the commas in the number group in a subsequent step.

```
$temp_comment =~ tr/,//d;             # remove commas in the whole string
```

or

```
$temp_comment =~ s/(?<=\d),(?=\s\d)//g;  # remove commas between numbers '11, 22'
```

For "single step", you have to use the `/e` modifier:

```
$temp_comment =~ s{ ^                 # line start
                    \s*               # leading blanks?
                    CR                # CR tag
                    \D*               # non-number stuff
                    ((?:\d+ [,\s]*)+) # single or group of numbers
                    \D*               # non number stuff
                    $                 # line end
                  }
                  {do{(local$_=$1)=~y/,//d;$_}}mxeg;
```

This will, on the data above, result in:

```
1234
2345 3456 45 567
678
```

But really, **please use**, if possible,  **the simpler two step approach**. The latter regex might be a maintainance nightmare for your successors.

Comment: I need it to separate each set of digit that are grouped in the input. such as CR1234, 111, 333, 3453, 55555 this would ideally turn into "1234 111 333 3453 55555" or even this 1234 \n 111 \n 333 \n 3453 \n 55555

Comment: How **exactly** looks your input data? Do you have single lines? Or a $variable with newlines `\n` between the lines (as in my posting)? How exactly follows your output from input dat? What about newlines?

Comment: a new line in between data lines. like yours above.  And the second one you typed up works or atleast better, I think I just need to turn the commas into new line characters

Comment: Thanks for all your help I used your second idea and then just did another line to change the commas to new line characters.

Comment: could you put comments in to explain your steps in that one like you did in the last one? some parts are a little over my head still

Comment: is there a way to replace only the commas between the numbers with \n? Instead of replacing all the commas in the string with \n like I am currently doing with this...
$temp_comment =~ s/,/\n/g;

Comment: `(?<=\d),(?=\s\d)` - means: *replace only if* comma after number `(?<=\d),` and comma before space and number `,(?=\s\d)`.

Comment: Also replacing the CR tag with the old one [cC][rR] it will still work the same I believe.  Because sometimes when someone inputs their data the cr is lower cases and possibly the "s" if it was crs but I believe that lower case s does not matter as it is disregarded now.  Either way thanks for all your help!!!

Answer (score 1):

You may be better off doing this in two steps:

1) Create your regular expression

`s/\s[cC][rR][-\s:;]*([\d\ ]+)/\n$1/mg` (note the new way to capture all of the numbers, you're only capturing the first number above)

2) Then just strip out the commas in the string with find/replace.

Answer (score 1):

```
my ($v) = /CR[s ]*((?:\d+[\s,]*)*)/ig;
$v =~ s/,//g;
print $v,"\n";
```

Comment: For a perl newbie (the OP), you should probably add the context of the expression (`$_`) and point out the difference between the original **replacement** and your **matching**.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following will work for you:

```
use Modern::Perl;

say join ' ', (/(\d+)/g) for <DATA>;

__DATA__
CR1234: "Then some text"
CRs 1111, 2222, 33, 444
CR567 "Some Text"
```

Output:

```
1234
1111 2222 33 444
567
```

Hope this helps!